# Some kind of a Manova with repeated measures

Tags: r, mixed-model, manova

I have a question that is somewhere between R and stats I guess...

Let's set up the situation: I have a test that gives 4 scores, corresponding to 4 different dimensions of a problem. We can assume the data are relatively well distributed, and accept the normality assumptions and all that stuff.

The patients carried a surgery, and I have multiple measures before (1 to 3 measures, one per year), and after (2 to 5, one per year).

**I want to know if there is an effect of the surgery.**

**Simple solution**

If I want to analyze the scores separately, it's relatively easy, and I will use a linear mixed model, where I want to explain the score by the time and by what we can call the period (before or after the surgery). The patient is included as random effects. In this model, I can test if there is a surgery effect, adjusting to natural evolution.

The main pitfall of this strategy is that, as I am analyzing 4 different scores, I should adjust the p-values with a multiplicity correction method, say Holm's method. This will impact the power of my analysis...

**Manova**

The problem is finally a problem of *multivariate ANOVA with repeated measures*. Thus, what I am looking for, is an extension of the previous strategy, so that I can put all my scores together. I should include then a new variable dimension, saying what is the corresponding dimension of the measure.

I feel that the problem is nearly solved, however, I'm pretty sure there is a big issue with the options to specify: what kind of correlation matrix?

**So, does this problem inspire someone?**

And, bonus points: I will have to implement it in R...

So far, I have no data to share, I have not reached the simulation phase, and the real data are not yet available... I'm writing the analysis plan...

Thank you for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a multivariate mixed effects model. In R, there is the `sabreR` package and an [accompanying book](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/9780429191602):

The only other package in R that fits such a model natively, as far as I know, is `MCMCglmm`. I can also think of some non-native alternatives; one is to use BUGS or JAGS which both have an R interface and are free but you would have to code the model from scratch. Another is MPlus which is not free but has an R interface and finally in Stata (again, not free but does have an R interface) you could try GLLAMM.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as accepted. If not, please let us know why. Thanks !